# Rigging: editing bones and mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

During my rigging process I’ve decided to make the legs of my character a little shorter. I do not have any drivers or shape keys. Just already weighted bones.How do I approach this?
Can I just edit the mesh in edit mode?
Also, the bones then need to be scaled down a bit. Can I do that in pose mode?
Do I need to unparent? If yes, how do I do that and then parent back to the armature after I’ve made the changes?